# Marionette JS and Wreqr

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on following the tutorials on backbonerails.com learning Marionette. It looks like the videos were written using version 1 but that in version 2 the messaging system has changed and uses wreqr.

I've been trying to translate the code using the wreqr github examples but keep getting errors. If anyone could help me translate this code into the current marionette request/response system I'd really appreciate it! I've been having trouble finding any current examples.

Current code in the entities file:

```
@Demo.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class Entities.Header extends Backbone.Model

    class Entities.HeaderCollection extends Backbone.Collection
      model: Entities.Header

    API = 
      getHeaders: ->
        new Entities.HeaderCollection [
        { name: "Users" }
        { name: "Leads" }
        { name: "Appointments" }
      ]

    App.reqres.addHandler "header:entities", ->
      API.getHeaders()
```

Code in the header controller requesting the entities:

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Controller = 

    listHeader: ->
      links = App.reqres.request "header:entities"
      console.log links
      headerView = @getHeaderView links
      App.headerRegion.show headerView

    getHeaderView: (links) ->
      new List.Headers
        collection: links
```

Comment: Sorry, can't really spot what the problem is, but have you checked the latest docs? I find they are really helpful: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.0.1/

Comment: The pretty much just mention that there is a global messaging system and point to the wreqr docs. Which throw an error when I try to add the code in similar to how they're listed by listed a variable first - https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**addHandle** which was placed in the entity does not exist.
Replace by **setHandler**, invoke this event using **request**, Eg.

```
# entities
App.reqres.setHandler "header: entities", ->
  API.getHeaders()

# controller
links = App.reqres.request links "header: entities"
```

The setHandler function, has responsibility in **adding** your **event trigger** along with the **callback and context**, take a look at the [source code from the marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L223).

I did a sample in the latest version from the marionette.
I'm using the Wreqr to exchange events with the API of the entity, for [more details see in this project](https://github.com/SauloSilva/backbone-marionette-example).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not sure why this worked after the 10th time I tried it per the Wreqr docs but this now works for setting the handler:

```
App.reqres = new Backbone.Wreqr.RequestResponse

App.reqres.setHandler "header:entities", ->
  API.getHeaders()
```